# ATSAMD51G19 Help setting up Digital output with clock source

Tags: c, embedded, clock, internals

I cant seem to get my head round configuring the internal clock as an output.

I'm looking to output a 32MHz clock on PA22 or Digital Pin 1 on the adafruit metro M4 Express.

here is my code

```
void setup()
{   

    GCLK->GENCTRL[7].reg = GCLK_GENCTRL_OE |              // Enable the GCLK output
                           GCLK_GENCTRL_IDC |            // Set the duty cycle to 50/50 HIGH/LOW
                           GCLK_GENCTRL_GENEN |
                           GCLK_GENCTRL_SRC_DFLL;           

    while(GCLK->SYNCBUSY.bit.GENCTRL7);          

    PORT->Group[g_APinDescription[1].ulPort].PINCFG[g_APinDescription[1].ulPin].bit.PMUXEN = 1;

    PORT->Group[g_APinDescription[1].ulPort].PMUX[g_APinDescription[1].ulPin >> 1].reg |= PORT_PMUX_PMUXO(1);
}
```

any help much appreciated

Comment: Getting _anything_ out on ports on these parts is quite painful, you have to wade through their obscure mux tables. The "magic number" you give to PMUX have to correspond to the correct "magic letter" in the mux table. From what I can tell, GCLK_IO is magic letter H, but you seem to be using magic letter G?